# ListView doesnt appear after called finish(), and reopen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm getting data through PHP and set to listview..
First i open the application , the listview will show out, but after called finish and reopen the application , the listview will not appear and need to call refresh to make it re-appear ..

FeedAdapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){


    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_feed, parent, false);
    TextView username = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);

    MovieFeed moviefeed = localmovies.get(position);

    username.setText(moviefeed.getUsername());


    return row;
}
```

Tab1 fragment with listview

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);

    tweetListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.tweetList);


        urlString = "http://idonno.net/G.php"; //json url
        new ProcessJSON().execute(urlString);
        tweetItemArrayAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), localmovies);
     tweetListView.setAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter);

return v;


}
```

Comment: Do you notify adapter after your background task finished?

Comment: Nope… i added just now but cant run… wherw should i notify?

Comment: I think you are using AsyncTask. You just need to notify after JSON parsing process  and adding objects to arraylist done(OnPostExecute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement an asyncTask and make sure that you really have the data before instantiating the listview. Like in this example with a anonymous inner class.

```
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listings);
            lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(YourActivity.this, shares));
        }
    });

}
```

If you update the list anytime you should call `notifyDataSetChanged()`on your adapter.

You could separate the asyncTask too like the accepted answer for this question [How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Comment: Thanks, i just moved my tweetItemArrayAdapter = new FeedAdapter(getActivity(), localmovies);
     tweetListView.setAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter); from onCreate to onPostexecute, and the problem has been solved.. TQ so much